# Overlay text forced out of containing div

Tags: css, wordpress

I've tried this yesterday and it worked fine for me, it's basic enough, I just want to have a few lines of text overlay a background image (at 'nk'). Somewhere something has gone wrong - when the background image is at full size (which only seems to be possible by adding a png transparent image - full height not full width - to 'fill' it out) then the text seems to be forced from the containing div and its background image.

I'm using a drag and drop builder called Visual Composer, in this you can work with rows - .histy is the class I've attached to the problem div/row

and here is the page with the text problem:

http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=2755

Any ideas why now the text is being forced out of the containing div ? Thanks.

CSS for this page:

```
#container {
margin: 0%;
}

#container text area {
margin: 5%;
}

wrapper {
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

entry {
box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
padding: 0px;
}

entry-header.style {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}

.entry-content a img,
 #attachment-nav a img {
max-width: 98.5%;
padding: 0%;
box-shadow:0 0 3px #EEE;
background:#FFF;
border:#EEE 1px solid;
}

.entry-title {
   display:none;
}

.single .entry, .page .entry, .error404 .entry {
margin-bottom: 5.1% !important;
padding: 0;
}

#site-title {
height:100%;
width:100%;
} 

#site-title, #site-description {
line-height: 100%;
}

#site-title {
margin: 0 0;
}

#site-title img {
margin: 0;
}

#site-title img {
padding: 0;
}

#access {
background: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/03   
/HISTORY-MENU-TOP.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
}

.histy {
background: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/06   
/HISTORY-1-NT.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: contain;
}

.tourguides {
margin-top: 20px;
}

.walkback {
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.walktrans {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.walktext {
background-color: transparent;
}

.walktext {
margin-top: 2.0vh;
}

.walktext p {
font-size: 24px;
font-size: 2.8vw;
}

.walktext p {
padding-left: 0.8vw;
padding-right: 2.5vw;
}

.walktext a {
color: #BD8346;
}

.walktext a:hover {
color: #827265;
}

.trailmenu h4 {
font-size: 23px;
}

.trailmenu h4 {
overflow: auto;    
}

.trailmenu h4 span {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 3px;
}

.trailmenu h4 span{
display: block;
float: left;
}

.trailmenu h4 img{
float: right; 
padding-top: 10px;       
}​

.trailmenu h4 img {
vertical-align:text-bottom;
}

h5 {
font-size: 21px;
}

h5 {
overflow: auto;    
}

h5 span {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 3px;
}

h5 span{
display: block;
float: left;
}

h5 img{
float: right; 
padding-top: 20px;       
}​

h5 img {
vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: Posting your whole CSS isn't going to help understanding your problem. Can you please post a Jsfiddle of the issue? or be more specific on explaining the problem?

Comment: Do you mean the "I am text block. Click edit button to change this text."? That text is sitting in a `<p>` tag outside the containing `<div>` of the background. Move it into the same containing `<div>` if you want it to be inside.

Comment: I'm using Visual Composer - a drag and drop builder - which uses columns as containing divs and which allows you to nest various elements - images, text boxes etc. within these divs. In this problem column or div I have a transparent png image and the text box which is being forced down somehow out of the column as can be seen - I am text block. Click edit button to change this text